# Why does AWS Glue say "Max concurrent runs exceeded", when there are no jobs running?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

I have an AWS Glue job, with max concurrent runs set to 1. The job is currently not running. But when I try to run it, I keep getting the error: "Max concurrent runs exceeded".

Deleting and re-creating the job does not help. Also, other jobs in the same account run fine, so it cannot be a problem with account wide service quotas.

Why am I getting this error?

Comment: Glue is honestly one of the absolute worst of AWS' services, the UI is horrendous, the API for getting table / partition information is slow, and the jobs have these kinds of bugs. Often times we cannot run our jobs because AWS temporarily does not have enough resources available - nice one...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I raised this issue with AWS support, and they confirmed that it is a known bug:

> I would like to inform you that this is a known bug, where an internal distributed counter that keeps track of job concurrency goes into a stale state due to an edge case, causing this error. Our internal Service team has to manually reset the counter to fix this issue. Service team has already added the bug fix in their product roadmap and will be working on it. Unfortunately I may not be able to comment on the ETA on the deployment, as we don’t have any visibility on product teams road map and fix release timeline.

The suggested workarounds are:

- Increase the max concurrency to 2 or higher
- Re-create the job with a different name

Comment: Increasing the max concurrency >1 introduces it's own set of complications however as this can interfere with bookmarks. However if you manually run a status check via the API on a job or workflow before you trigger it to make sure that it is not running you can sort of manually set the max concurrency to 1. For example I am triggering a set of workflow via Step Functions and I'm checking the status of every workflow before I trigger it. If the workflow is currently running the machine goes into a wait loop until the status is "COMPLETED", waits 1 minute, then starts the next run.

Comment: @RCB Do you have an update from AWS? I am getting the same exception and their answers don't provide workarounds

Comment: @bogdan.rusu No, unfortunately not.

Answer (score 3):

Glue container is start and its taking some time same when your job end container shutdown taking some time in between if you try to execute new Jon and default concurrency is 1 so you will get this error.

**How to resolve:**
Go to your Glue Job  --> Under Job detail tab you can find "Maximum concurrency" default value is 1 change it to 3 or more as per your need.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I tried changing "Maximum concurrency" to 2 and then run it !
It worked but again running it cause the same issue, but I looked into my s3 ,it has dumped the data ,so it run for once!

I'm still looking for a stable solution but this may work!